# How can I create javascript on my server that uses backend on that server and will be used on another web site?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, xss

I need to offer a web service that my clients can use on their web sites with AJAX. They are not able to call my web service because of XSS preventions. The clients can not make a proxy to access my web service.

I am trying to make a javascript library on my server that they could include in their site, which would in turn call the web service on the server. Somehow it does not seem to work.

The server is located at Google App Engine.

So the question is: How can I make a javascript library on my server that uses backend on that server and remote users can use it? Much like google maps js API works?

Comment: Any JS you provide will be subsumed into their environment - it will not have any extra privileges based on where it was loaded from. Google Maps integration works over JSON-P, which is the standard get-around where cross-domain AJAX is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) instead, just set CORS http headers for your web service.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://clientsite.com http://client.website.com
```

Same origin policy is dependant on document origin therefore providing a JavaScript library will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- have your javascript library create an iframe pointed at your server. Communicate between the code running in that iframe and the 3rd-party site via the best crosspage communication for the browser you're on. Google's Closure library has a class called [CrossPageChannel](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/closure/goog/net/xpc/crosspagechannel.js?r=1024) that works very well for this. Put the bulk of your logic in the iframe. This can be nice because it'll prevent the 3rd-party site from doing anything that isn't well-defined by the messages you pass across the iframe boundary.
- use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to get data from your server and keep all the logic in the javascript library.